# Got an error while trying to create SSL certificate on OVH VPS server

Tags: ssl, vps, certbot, ovh

I tried to install an SSL certificate via certbot on my VPS server but i got the following error.

> ```
> 2021-05-14 05:15:19,038:ERROR:certbot._internal.log:An unexpected error occurred:
> 2021-05-14 05:15:19,038:ERROR:certbot._internal.log:TypeError: create_record() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'
> ```

```
sudo certbot certonly --dns-ovh --dns-ovh-credentials /root/.ovhapi -d thomasmerat.com -d *.thomasmerat.com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator dns-ovh, Installer None
Requesting a certificate for thomasmerat.com and *.thomasmerat.com
Performing the following challenges:
dns-01 challenge for thomasmerat.com
dns-01 challenge for thomasmerat.com
Cleaning up challenges
Encountered exception during recovery: TypeError: delete_record() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'
An unexpected error occurred:
TypeError: create_record() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'
```

Does anyone have an idea what could cause that error message ?
Thank you

Comment: What is your cerbot & python version ? `cerbot --version` & `/usr/bin/python --version`

Comment: i fixed it by using snap instead of pip. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I fixed the file .../certbot/plugins/**dns_common_lexicon.py**

Change the argument name *type* with *rtype* line 48 :

```
        self.provider.create_record(rtype='TXT', name=record_name, content=record_content)
```

and line 70 :

```
        self.provider.delete_record(rtype='TXT', name=record_name, content=record_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by using snap instead of pip. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue while downgrading dns-lexicon

```
pip install dns-lexicon==3.3.22
```